# JavaScript Validation on DropDown in classic asp page

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a classic asp page in which i'm going ot have a new drop down. This new dropdown will only appear on the page if it meets certain criteria. I need to add a validation such that the user is required to select the dropdown whenever it is displayed on the page before being able to submit the page and whenever the dropdown is not appearing on the page the validation is not required

I'm having trouble in the validation part

Below is my code that i have on the classic asp page for the dropdown

```
<select id= "BatchElement<%=vRptCount%>"  name="BatchElement<%=vRptCount%>" <%if SR("rptdesc1") = "N" then response.write " style='Display:none' "   %> > 
  <option value=0 selected>--------------------Select--------------------</option>
  <option value="Deidentified"  <%if SR("BatchElement") = "Deidentified" then%> selected<%end if%>>Deidentified</option>
  <option value="Identified"  <%if SR("BatchElement") = "Identified" then%>selected<%end if%>>Identified</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```js
vBatchElement = "BatchElement" + vReportCounts
if(document.all(vBatchElement).value==0) { 
  alert("Please Select BatchElement from the dropdown value for "+vReportCounts);
  return false;
```

With the Above Javascript the validation seems to work even if the dropdwon is not appearing on the page. How do i make the validation work such that it only validates when the dropdown appears on the page

Comment: Why render the Javascript and dropdown if it's not necessary?

Comment: the dropdown is a required thing when a certain crietria is met and the user has to select some value within the dropdown .

Answer (score 1):

Your control is a drop down so you shouldn't attempt to access the "value" of the control, you should access the selected index's value (when validating against a specific value selected) or simply the control's selected index if all you care about is that something other than the first item is selected.

I'm not sure exactly how you are initiating the JS call or how you are getting your asp variable "vRptCount" into your javascript function as "vReportCounts" but assuming that is all happening correctly, maybe something more like this:

```
vBatchElement = "BatchElement" + vReportsCounts;

var ddl = document.getElementByID(vBatchElement);
if(ddl) {
if(ddl.selectedIndex == 0)){
alert('Please select BatchElement from the dropdown value for ' + vReportCounts);
return(false);
}
```